# Storing a unique set of keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

I have a unique set of model primary keys (strings or ints) that I want to cache in memory.

I will be testing for the existence of a key in the set and also adding and removing keys from the set.

I am tempted to use the 'key' side of a standard array and perform the operations thus:

```
$keys[$key] = 1    // add
unset($keys[$key]) // remove
isset($keys[$key]) // check existence
```

But this feels like I'm using the wrong tool for the job as I do not need the 'value' side of the array (set to 1). I had a look at the `SPLHeap` classes as well and am tempted to use one of these instead.

I imagine this is a fairly common problem, which is the best structure to use here?

Comment: I think your own suggested solution of using array keys to implement set semantics is actually not such a weird one. I know that some of Java's `Set` implementations use an underlying `Map` internally (which basically has the same interface as a PHP array). Sun/Oracle engineers probably know what they're doing :)

Comment: SPLHeap certainly wouldn't be the correct datastructure to use, because a heap is all about __sorted__ access to data that it contains, and PHP's heap implementation empties itself after a single traversal

Comment: This is actually not a bad technique in my opinion; definitely something I've seen done quite a bit in php.

Comment: Why not just store the primary keys as values in the array? `$keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', ...]`

Comment: @upful because finding/deleting an element would require traversing the values O(n).

Comment: If you use `in_array()` and `array_diff()` you can handle checking existence and removal without traversing

Comment: @upful: internally PHP is traversing. There is no difference if you are doing it or if PHP is doing it.